# Doubt regarding elliptical orbits and eccentricity relation with masses

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, planets, satellites

I was working with Roche's Limit , You can visit the wikipedia page on Roche's Limit and Hill's Sphere (not important here). A query raised in my mind about the elliptical orbit in which the moon is revolving around earth while earth being the on one of the focii of the ellipse .  So I was wondering how do I find the relation between eccentricity of ellipse and mass of moon and mass of earth . Is it possible to find such relation. If not I am sorry but there must be some mathematical relation between the elliptical properties and mass of earth and mass of moon . Or let it be more  general How do I find the eccentricity of ellipse and knowing that there is some mass $m1$ revolving in elliptical orbit around a mass $m2$ $(m2>m1)$
. As my friend G.smith pointed out that there is no relation between the conic sections and mass , I have a greater curiosity in knowing relations between purely mathematical things and physical quantities like mass , energy etc. If there is no such relation , please tell why not possible

Comment: *How do I find the eccentricity of ellipse If I know the length of major axis and minor axis?* [Wikipedia!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Eccentricity)

Comment: The relationship between the major axis, the minor axis, and the eccentricity of an ellipse is *geometrical*; i.e., purely mathematical. It has nothing to do with masses, gravity, Newtonian mechanics, or any other aspect of physics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation

Comment: On the other hand, if you wanted to compute the eccentricity from, say,  the masses, initial positions, and initial velocities, that would involve physics.

Comment: @G.Smith But how can we conclude that there is no relationship between masses and conic section , there can be we are maybe just unaware of it

Comment: No. Conic sections are pure geometry. You intersect a cone with a plane, and get ellipses, parabolas, hyperbolas, etc. This has nothing to do with physics. Mass is a physics concept and does not exist in geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eccentricity of the moon's orbit is not constant. It's value oscillates significantly during the course of a synodic month, and there are also secular changes that occur on longer time scales.